# How do I make a subject with newlfm

Tags: packages, letters

I can't find in the documentation anything about how to make a subject in a newlfm style letter. What I would like is something like the following.

**Överklagande av Skatteverkets beslut om tilläggstaxering,
dnr 15-2008/0057**

Jag vill överklaga Skatteverkets beslut om ...

Answer (score 2):

A less ugly solution is replacing the "regarding" text by "Object" :

in the preamble :

```
\PhrRegard{Object}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Providing a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) or explaining a bit about what this does would be nice. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Haha! I found a way to make this work. It's an ugly solution though.

In the file "`newlfm.cls`" i made the following changes:

- In line 426 I changed `\PhrRegard{Regarding}` to `\PhrRegard{}`
- In line 1412 I removed the : from {`\@regard@phr`:
  `\@regard@line}{}`

In my `.tex`-file I wrote "`\regarding{\textbf{Överklagande av Skatteverkets beslut om tilläggstaxering,\\dnr 15-2008/0057}}`".

And it works!