# Centre aligning letter SUBJECT using newflm class

Tags: letters

I am using `newflm` class to prepare a letter. The class, surprisingly, does not provide a `Subject` field. Stealing idea from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11877/how-do-i-make-a-subject-with-newlfm), I somehow managed to insert a subject, though it was not at all a nice hack. But how to centre-align the subject now? Is there any solution without editing the class file itself? Below is an MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,addrfromleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter,epstopdf}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=20pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=10pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{PHONE}
\PhrEmail{EMAIL}
\PhrRegard{SUBJECT}

\namefrom{FROM\_PERSON}

\addrfrom{FROM\_ADDRESS}

\regarding{CENTER\_ALIGN\_SUBJECT\_HERE}

\addrto{TO\_ADDRESS}

\greetto{GREETINGS,}
\closeline{CLOSING}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}


LETTER\_BODY\_HERE

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

It produces a letter like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer not to redefine macros set in the class, you could simply do

```
 \regarding{{\centering CENTER\_ALIGN\_SUBJECT\_HERE \\}}
```

Otherwise you could patch the `\regarding` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\def\regarding#1{\setboolean{@pt@regard}{true}\protect\def\@regard@line{{\centering #1\\}}}%
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

The extra group `{}` around the subject limits the effect of `\centering` to that portion of the text and `\\` explicitly terminates the line inside the group, which is necessary because `\centering` modifies the behaviour of `\\` so that the right spacing is generated at the end of the line to center it.

Comment: `\regarding{\centering CENTER\_ALIGN\_SUBJECT\_HERE}` centre-aligns the LETTER_BODY_HERE text, too.

Comment: Same happens if I patch the macro.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock you are right, solved, see edit

Comment: Works perfectly. Out of curiosity, what is the need of two extra \`\\\` at the end? Also, why did you enclose `\centering CENTER\_ALIGN\_SUBJECT\_HERE\\\` within two curly braces?

Comment: see edit for a brief explanation

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock in this case could you mark my post as an answer?

Comment: Done, marked as answer